# How would i return a count of the total objects using Parse Rest API?

Tags: parse-platform

I am using the Parse Rest API and i would like to get a count of the total number of objects. I have tried using curl command on the command line by passing in the count=1 parameter as below :

```
curl -X GET
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <App ID Here>"
    -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <Rest Key Here>"
    https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Restaurant
    --data-urlencode 'count=0'
```

But i get all the results. In this possible with Parse.com or i will have to use code and count on the client side code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you dont want get all results you can add limit params, like so:

```
curl -X GET
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <App ID Here>"
    -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <Rest Key Here>"
    https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Restaurant
    --data-urlencode 'count=1'
    --data-urlencode 'limit=0'
```

Source : https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-counting